# getting syntax error in teradat. whats wrong in this query?

Tags: teradata

```
SELECT sysxml.XPathValue(O.CAST(xmlOrder VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE), '//ORDER/PO_NUMBER/*') AS PO_Number,
       sysxml.XPathValue(O.CAST(xmlOrder VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE), '//ORDER/DATE/*') AS theDate
FROM   COMMON.OrderLog O
WHERE  sysxml.XPathValue(O.CAST(xmlOrder VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE), '//ORDER/BILLTO/*') = 'Mike';
```

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow

Answer (score 1):

The `CAST` is not part of `O`, and `xmlOrder` probably is.
So instead of this:

```
O.CAST(xmlOrder ...
```

you probably need to do this in all three lines:

```
CAST(O.xmlOrder ...
```

Comment: And the `AS` is missing, too: `(CAST(O.xmlOrder VARCHAR(1000) AS CHARACTER SET UNICODE)`

Comment: SELECT XPathValue(CAST(o.xmlOrder as VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE), '//ORDER/PO_NUMBER/*') AS PO_Number,
            XPathValue(CAST(o.xmlOrder as VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE), '//ORDER/DATE/*') AS theDate
    FROM COMMON.OrderLog O
    WHERE  XPathValue(CAST(o.xmlOrder as VARCHAR(1000) CHARACTER SET UNICODE),'//ORDER/BILLTO/*') = 'Mike';

Comment: Corrected the query as above but still getting same error.

Comment: Ok, what's the actual error message? This seems to be copied directly from the DDL manuals, but there's no function with that name (Maybe there was one in older releases). You should check the XML manual for existing functions like `XMLEXTRACT

Comment: Thank you very much dnoeth and Peter. Yes query example is picked from old manual. i am trying to replicate the result as my requirement is similar. Is XMLEXTRACT same as XPathValue? By the way error message is 3706: expected something between '(' and CAST.....                       i have picked this info from link http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1144_151K/example_parsing_an_xml_document_using_a_scalar_udf_CREATE_REPLACE_FUNCTION_EXT.html

Comment: @Altaaf: It's similar, e.g. `xmlOrder.XMLEXTRACT('//ORDER/PO_NUMBER/*','')`